# Mean stack & PrimeNG CSV export - nested array of objects as new row

Tags: export-to-csv, mean-stack, primeng, primeng-table

I have a multiple level nested array that I would like to export. I'm just wondering if I can export the nested array of objects as a new row of csv? At the moment, I'll have to input "users.0.name" as field in order to get the data of the array of objects instead of [Object Object],[Object Object],[Object Object]. I tried to do a loop on the this.cols but it doesn't work. I'm thinking to create another record of the same data but with just one user so that I can export one user for each row of data. Is this possible? Thank you in advance!

example of data:

```
[
users: [ 
{
  id: 9845397834, 
  name: "John", 
  title: {...}
},
{
  id: 65156169834, 
  name: "Mary", 
  title: {...}
},
{
  id: 8965134, 
  name: "Jane", 
  title: {...}
},
],
phone: "",
email: ""
]
```